# Ping ipv6 localhost fails address family for hostname not supported

Tags: 22.04, ipv6, localhost

A year or so ago I tweaked my IPV6 config to disable it, or at last that's what I tough. I don't remember which commands executed or which articles I read. Currently I'm at LM Cinnamon 21.2 (Ubuntu 22.04)

Today, using a debugger for my work, it generates a web service URL like this

> "webSocketDebuggerUrl":
> "ws://[::1]:8081/inspector/debug?device=0&page=-1"

And the debugger software fails to connect to it, because, somehow, the debugger web service gets the IPv6 of localhost. If I try to ping localhost I get: `ping ipv6 address Address family for hostname not supported`

Trying to ping ::1 I get `ping6: connect: Network unreachable`

What can I do to get my localhost ipv6 running?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. It seems that I have created a conf file in sysctl.d **/etc/sysctl.d/99-disable-ipv6.conf**, inside I had set

```
# Disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

So reverting net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 to 0 solved the issue at startup!